# using YT JS API code to get embed video code

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, swfobject, youtube-javascript-api

I am trying to use the Youtube JavaScript method of calling on the SWF file, I am using FancyBox and I've added certain buttons already such as a grab code button so my users can grab the embed code. So this is my script so far from reading their API documentation.

```
 ytplayer = document.getElementById("fancybox-swf");
 ytplayer.getVideoEmbedCode();
```

The Error I am getting is this

```
TypeError: Object #<HTMLObjectElement> has no method 'getVideoEmbedCode'
```

I've tried many ways so far, such as adding the SWFObject.js and that still gives the same error. The HTML of the Object looks like this:

```
<object id="fancybox-swf" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="100%" height="100%">
<param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/fa38VnZpaL0?enablejsapi=1">
<param name="wmode" value="transparent">
<param name="allowfullscreen" value="true">    
<param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
<embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/fa38VnZpaL0?enablejsapi=1" 
       type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
       width="100%" height="100%"
       wmode="transparent" 
       allowfullscreen="true" 
       allowscriptaccess="always">
 </object>
```

I only want to get the Embed Code, and maybe some other documentation after learning some more of this, the problem actually getting this at all, so far I've been trying this in Console as to not destroy my overall FancyBox code. I will integrate this later on in the `beforeShow` or `afterShow` which ever one actually works.

I only need some guidance for the Documentation that youtube has is just confusing me more and more. Can anyone help me with some help and lead me the correct way.

Comment: `getVideoEmbedCode()` is a method of the youtube player object, not the DOM element. You have to initialize the youtube player before to be able to use API methods like here: http://jsfiddle.net/JC4wg/

Comment: @roasted so since I am using the FancyBox code, this isn't possible then? If I am correct.

Comment: I wouldn't say it isn't possible, a workaround should still be possible.

Comment: I just used a code from youtube with the iframe embed, and used the fancybox `this.href` in a global variable and that is what I use in the src of the iframe